# Using If statement to add a timestamp if a tick box has been ticked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which contains a tick box (cell C36). I have changed the data validation so when ticked, the cell = 1 and when un-ticked it = 0.

Now i would like a script that when C36 = 1, it puts a time stamp (HH:mm) in B39 without using the NOW() function and when C36 = 0, it B39 should be blank/empty.

I have tried using the NOW() function but that updates every time something is changed on the page and i want it static from the time it is ticked. I have used an If/else script but it either doesn't input anything in the cell or it will always have the time, even if the box is not ticked.

```
function onEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Page 1');
  var time = ss.getRange('B39');
  var tick = ss.getRange('C36');

  if(tick =='1'){
    time.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("HH:mm");
  }

  else if (tick =='0'){
    time.setValue("");
}
}
```

Comment: How does one tick a tick box? Does the tick bite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
    function onEdit(e){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Page 1');
        var range = e.range;
  Logger.log(range.getColumn()+ " "+range.getRow())
  if (range.getColumn() != 3) 
  {Logger.log("wrong column")
  return;}
  if (range.getRow() != 36) return;
  var prettyTime= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Los_Angeles', "HH:mm" );
  var B39 = ss.getRange(39,2);
  if (range.getValue() == true) 
    B39.setValue(prettyTime);
  if (range.getValue()== false) 
    B39.setValue("n/a");
```

Your problem before is that it was doing stuff regardless of which cell was edited.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much.

Comment: So this does work, however, i have 2x tickboxes which i want to use it in and when i duplicate it to the 2nd , only 1 will work at a time.